# is $\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^m}\right)}$ divergent or convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

is $$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^m}\right)}$$ divergent or convergent. If its divergent are there any lower bounds for n and/or m that would make it convergent. I know that it is divergent if n or m is less than 1 but I'm not sure for higher values

Comment: Take a look at Riemann's zeta function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reversing the order of summation, this is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac1{n^m}
=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$$
as this series telescopes.

Comment: Written differently as in $\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{1}{j^2} + \sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{1}{j^3} + \sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{1}{j^4} + ... = 1$, this is fascinating I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since for any $m\geq 2$ we have $\zeta(m)-1=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx $ it is pretty straightforward that

$$ \sum_{m\geq 2}\left(\zeta(m)-1\right) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)}\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\,dx = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The series is:
$$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^m}+\frac{1}{4^m}+\cdots\right)$$
Use the ratio test:
$$\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} \frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}=\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{4^{m+1}}+\cdots}{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{3^m}+\frac{1}{4^m}+\cdots}<1$$
The series converges.